# How to make boostrap reflow colums if window is wide, but the columns are in a narrow element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I know that bootstrap automatically reflows columns based on device width using `@media` queries, but is there a way to make the columns reflow if they happen to be in a narrow element?

[Here's a fiddle illustrating what I'm talking about.](https://jsfiddle.net/w1g62j7d/) (make sure to make the result section wide).

I want the lower two columns to always reflow since they are in a fixed width, narrow element. The trick is to do it without changing the HTML since my template is reused in more than one place (unless the changes don't affect other uses).

Comment: I am unsure how you define `reflow`, from my definition it already does. Could you explain a bit more what you want to happen with the two lowest columns?

Comment: Instead of being side by side, I want the left column to be on top of the right on bottom, and both taking up 100% of the parent element width. Basically what happens if you have a narrow viewport. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Ahh, so you want the narrow effect even on huge screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show you the "narrow effect" even when the screen is wider than 768px. It will affect all classes with a name starting with `col-sm-` inside a class called `narrow`.

```css
.narrow div[class^='col-sm-'] {
  width: 100%;
}
```